# android studio. read and write error when testing on mobile device

Tags: java, android-studio

I've followed this tutorial to create a read/write app, however when testing on my mobile device I get an 'unfortunately the app has stopped'. Any ideas why this may be? I'm writing to external storage sd card. If you have a simpler method of reading/writing files (preferably to internal storage) could you suggest it please.

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3pyyQbwLko

Comment: Please post your source code here, as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and include any relevant steps for building and all error messages (with stack trace) you may get. I don't think many people will bother to watch a video, especially not a tutorial, as opposed to what your actual code looks like.